# Are a bearing and C-clip all you need to replace a from wheel bearing?

Tags: wheels, bearing, wheel-bearing

I need to double check this. My front wheel bearing is busted(by someone eles analysis) on a citroen picasso 2006.

I have bought a bearing kit consisting of the bearing, a c clip and a nut.

I will have someone else replace the bearing but are these all the parts needed?

There are no other bushes/sleeves or whatever needed?

Comment: see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/65650/10976